# How to query exactly keywords with position in Solr Apache

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any way to query exactly keywords with position in Solr Apache.
Ex I have document with summary is :

> "Robert 1988 and Christian 1986"

Then I query keyword : ("Christian" *1988*).
It must be return 0 result. But It still return the record above.
Please help me.

Comment: `keyword:"Christian 1986"`?

Comment: `keyword:"Christian 1988"`?

Comment: Brother simply change you field type to string. I think this could solve your issue

Comment: but if the document is "Robert born: 1988 and Christian born:1986" and then I have query keyword: "Christian" 1988.How this query return zero result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default solr applies "OR" operator while querying, meaning that for query -

**summary: Christian 1988**

Internally query is translated as - **summary:Christian OR default search field:1988** hence you are getting the results

For querying exact phrases, you can use double quotes around your phrase like -
**summary: "Christian 1988"**

This should return you 0 results.

Comment: `summary: Christian 1988` does not get translated to `summary:Christian OR summary:1988` - ignoring the space after summary, it gets translated to `summary:Christian OR <default search field>:1988`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, you are correct, default search field will be used, I have edited the answer

Comment: but if the document is "Robert born: 1988 and Christian born:1986"
and then I have query keyword: "Christian" 1988.How this query return zero result